# Print a Winform/visual element

Tags: c#, winforms

All the articles I've found via google are either obsolete or contradict one another.

What's the easiest way to print a form or, say, a richtextbox in c#? I think it's using the `PrintDiaglog` class by setting the `Document`, but how does this get converted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least in VS 2008, its very easy. It took me about a couple of minutes to code the answer after reading your question. Here's where I borrowed it from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx

I tested this, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Someone I know created a component that extends controls with a lot of properties that give you a lot of control over how the form prints.  It's worth a look.

[MCL PrintForm Helper Component](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=279707)