# C# Winfoms Printing

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

i have a winform, i want to print all the available data on the winform, lets say i have form full of labels, how to print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code sample is from [How to: Print a Windows Form (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx), found in a SO question titled ["Print a Winform/visual element"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307/print-a-winform-visual-element), which is on the first page of the [search results for "winforms printing"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=winforms+printing):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button printButton = new Button();
    private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();

    public Form1()
    {
        printButton.Text = "Print Form";
        printButton.Click += printButton_Click;
        printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;
        this.Controls.Add(printButton);
    }

    void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureScreen();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }

    Bitmap memoryImage;

    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Location.X, Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender,  
           System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;

could you please explaint what is this "printDocument1_PrintPage"

Comment: It's a method declared somewhere below in the code sample. The `+=` attaches it as an event handler to the `PrintPage` event. In the original sample, more verbose syntax is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp); //You can replace panel1 with thiswith a parent like a panel,etc.
    //now you have a bitmap just print it using a PrintDocument
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) 
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Psuedo

```
string printString = "";    
foreach(Label lbl in this.Controls){
     printString += lbl.Text + "\n";
}

Print(printString);
```