# How to get print of datagridvew in C#

Tags: c#

I have a datagirdview which have a sqlquery data. I want to print this. Please Tell me the code of print button. i am using C#

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print a Winform/visual element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307/print-a-winform-visual-element)

Comment: You forgot to say what you mean by "print this": the grid as it is displayed at any one moment, including scrollbars etc.; or the complete data in the grid (possibly in a different visual representation)? And esp. in the latter case, since there are so many possibilities and options concerning tooling, you should simply give some more detail (which libraries you are using, what you have considered & tried so far, etc.).

Comment: I want to print the data of DateGridView

Answer (score 1):

Check this code may be helpful for you :-

```
 using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Printing;

    public class Form1 :
        Form
    {
        private Button printButton = new Button();
        private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();

        public Form1()
        {
            printButton.Text = "Print Form";
            printButton.Click += new EventHandler(printButton_Click);
            printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
            this.Controls.Add(printButton);
        }

        void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CaptureScreen();
            printDocument1.Print();
        }


        Bitmap memoryImage;

        private void CaptureScreen()
        {
            Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            Size s = this.Size;
            memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender,  
               System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
        }



        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the article about it [The DataGridViewPrinter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13678/The-DataGridViewPrinter-Class). You can use this class to easily print DataGridView.

For example, you can add [PrintDocument component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) on your form from Toolbox and inside it's PrintPage event, write this:

```
 bool more = printer.DrawDataGridView(e.Graphics);
 if (more == true)
     e.HasMorePages = true;
```

where printer is DataGridViewPrinter object.

To print this document, you can add button and add this code into it's click event:

```
        printer = new DataGridViewPrinter(yourGridView, printDocument1, 
                      true, true, "title", this.Font, Color.Black, true);

        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example you can work with [how to print datagrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView)

Here is some code:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    //Open the print dialog
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();            
    printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
    printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;    
    //Get the document
    if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        printDocument1.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";                
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
    /*
    Note: In case you want to show the Print Preview Dialog instead of 
    Print Dialog then comment the above code and uncomment the following code
    */

    //Open the print preview dialog
    //PrintPreviewDialog objPPdialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    //objPPdialog.Document = printDocument1;
    //objPPdialog.ShowDialog();
}
```